# How to open a .RKV file from Wii ISO

Tags: modding, wii

So, a few days ago, I got the itch to try my hand at creating a modded version of one of my favorite Wii games: Star Wars: The Force Unleashed. However, when I unpacked the ISO, I noticed some of the files had the extension .RKV. I have scoured the internet in search of any information, but all I could find was that this file extension is typically associated with RKive archives. After going through all the trouble of getting that software to run on a Win95 VM, it too could not open the file. In fact, it said it wasn't even an RKive archive. I have spent all whole day researching with no progress, so if anyone could tell me what this file extension is and how to open it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try the [methods discussed in this thread](https://forum.xentax.com/viewtopic.php?t=15853&start=15)? Other modders report these steps worked for them on this particular Wii game.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you so much! That quickbms program is a godsend.

Comment: If that solves your problem, please consider writing up a guide as an answer, to help future users trying to do similar things.